# SendMessage, Trying to send F4

Tags: c#

My SendMessage signature:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

To get the window handle, I find the MainWindowHandle from the process I want to send messages to:

```
whandle = MemClass.Process.MainWindowHandle;
```

Here I'm trying to SendMessage to that process window: (0x73 = F4 key)

```
SendMessage(whandle, 0x73, 0, 0);
```

And It's obviously giving error, because I'm sending last 2 params as int instead of IntPtr:

```
IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam
```

Tested with this call:

```
SendMessage(whandle, 0x73, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

0 errors but it's not sending F4 to the window

How do I call this function correctly? I want to send F4 to a process window.

Comment: Maybe `IntPtr.Zero`?

Comment: Not working, 0 errors but it's not sending F4 to the window

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation for SendMessage(). The second parameter is the message you're trying to send. F4 is not a message. It's a key. At the minimum, you need to send `WM_KEYDOWN` with the key, followed by `WM_KEYUP`. Or you could instead do it the proper way with `SendInput`, which you can find samples of using by searching this site.

Comment: Thank you Ken, I was reading this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage
SendInput it's not good for my purpose because I have to send the input to a minimized window

Comment: Yep. That link says that the second parameter is `UINT msg`, which is again a message, not a key. The message is [WM_KEYDOWN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown) with the key value encoded in the WPARAM. It will also need to be followed by `WM_KEYUP`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter is the msg not the key, as: keyup (0x100) or keydown (0x101)

The third parameter is the key as 0x73 (F4)

```
SendMessage(whandle, 0x100, 0x73, IntPtr.Zero);
SendMessage(whandle, 0x101, 0x73, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: Focus, then `SendKeys.Send()`? Example: [UI Automation - Set Text for a another application's TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53835316/3110834)