# How to set focus to bottom when Notepad.exe is executed with System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()?

Tags: c#, winforms, text-files

Open the `History.txt` file with the following code:

```cs
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Notepad.exe", HistoryFilePath);
```

The `History.txt` file is made up of JSON, and users should scroll to the bottom to see the cumulative usage time.

Therefore, the user necessary to check the bottom of the `History.txt` file.

Can I execute this way correctly?

Comment: If Notepad has a commandline parameter that does that, you can add that to your call. I have no idea whether such a thing exists - I suspect it doesn't - but that's something for you to look into and nothing to do with VB.NET. Alternatively, you'd have to use Windows API calls to manipulate the Notepad window after it opens.

Comment: If you want to customize the behavior, why you are opening an external app (notepad)?

Comment: Anyways, you can send WM_SCROLL message or you can send PageDown key or Ctrl+A to the edit control of notepad. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53835316/3110834)

Comment: var proc = Process.Start(...); proc.WaitForInputIdle() to wait for it to start up,  SendKeys.Send("^{End}"); to move the caret to the end of the file.  Winforms required.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for great answer. According to your answer, I wrote a post about how I solved it and left it :D

Answer (score 0):

As per **@Hans Passant**'s comment, I solved it like this:

```cs
private void CommandTextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Enter)
    return;

  var command = CommandTextBox.Text.ToUpper();
  if (command == "@SHOWHISTORY")
  {
    var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Notepad.exe", HistoryFilePath);
    process.WaitForInputIdle();
    SendKeys.Send("^{End}"};
    CommandTextBox.Clear();
  }
}
```

Now, users can check the most recent cumulative usage time without scrolling cumbersomely!

Comment: They never had to _scroll cumbersomely_ - just needed to press `Ctrl-End` on the keyboard.